# This tag should not be [legal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I propose that we burninate the [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag. There is no reason for SO to have it. Of the 457 questions tagged with it, [244 of them (53%)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blegal%5D+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano) are closed of off-topic. I'm sure there are many more which should be closed, or are used improperly. It evens says in the tag wiki for [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal)

> If you’re using this tag here, your question is probably not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Then why do we even have this tag! It literally says you probably shouldn't be using this tag! So lets get rid of it, including its counterparts (gnu, licensing, open-source) by an edit, retag, [down vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/158100) or close vote/flag.

Make it go kaboom!

Comment: Before anyone starts, just start closing the OT questions and then vote to close/downvote so ROOMBA do its work.

Comment: I'm not sure if `truelicensing` is bad per sé. It appears to be a licensing management API, and API usage itself is generally on-topic. Still, might want to check if those questions are about the API use, or are about the licensing decisions

Comment: From the [truelicense] excerpt: *is a comprehensive open source license management engine and API for the Java Virtual Machine." So there should not be an issue with this tag.

Comment: [A question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550556/ive-found-my-software-as-cracked-download-on-internet-what-to-do) is "locked for historical reasons". Apart from the fact it is a pretty interesting topic for programmers, is it possible to remove the [tag:legal] now, or will it only disappear when the tag itself gets ritually cleansed?

Comment: If anything, maybe having the tag is good so when people add it they read it and reconsider posting the question here?

Comment: @CaptainMan that would assume that users read the tag wiki's when posting the question, half the time they don't even read the question

Comment: @Humble The question I suppose is will more people read the tag wiki or will more people be influenced by its existence. Regardless I think less people will be affected by absence of it than will be affected by reading it.

Comment: I have removed the reference to Programmers from the wiki excerpt as it was never really appropriate.

Comment: Law.SE is coming out of private beta in a few days, perhaps we can throw that into the tag wiki?  The questions will be on topic there, if they're good questions.

Comment: About most of these questions: Tags based on open source licenses or anything about open source development are on-topic at [Open Source](http://opensource.stackexchange.com). We accept license recommendations too :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## All off topic questions closed, thank you [everyone that helped!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

You can still help out in a few different ways:

#### Ensure future questions get closed quickly

Unfortunately, even with many of these tags having updated wiki guidance, people are still using these tags. To check to make sure these are still closed, use these searches:

[All open questions with these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+%5Bgpl%5D+or+%5Blgpl%5D+or+%5Bcopyright%5D+or+%5Bcreative-commons%5D)

#### Edit and delete closed questions to finish burning the tag.

- Current tags: [copyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyright) [gpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpl) [lgpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lgpl)

---

#### Done

- Tag is burninated:

  [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal) [cpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpl) [mpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpl) [non-gpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-gpl) [artistic-license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artistic-license) [disclaimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disclaimer) [trademark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trademark) [copyleft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyleft) [proprietary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proprietary) [mspl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mspl) [proprietary-software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proprietary-software) [patents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patents)  [intellectual-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) [terms-of-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terms-of-use) [closed-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closed-source) [agpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agpl) [gplv3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gplv3) [bsd-license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bsd-license) [apache-license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-license) [mit-license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-license) [commercial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commercial) [foss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foss)
- All questions are off-topic and closed or locked:

[gpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpl) [lgpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lgpl) [copyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyright) [creative-commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/creative-commons)

- All off-topic questions are closed, there are on-topic questions left:

[eula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eula) [gnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu) [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing) [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) [truelicense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truelicense)

Comment: 2617 open licensing questions suggest that [the way of code-golf](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759/839601) looks worth considering for these

Comment: @gnat these are on topic at Law.StackExchange, soon to be in public beta.

Comment: @dsolimano However, most of these questions are too old to migrate, and even so, you can't migrate questions to beta sites without extraordinary intervention.

Comment: @TylerH yeah I'm not proposing migration at this point, just some pointer somewhere that these questions are very much on topic on another Stack Exchange.

Comment: We are coming up on a more challenging stage of this cleanup.  The last 3 tags are likely to have many **on-topic** questions.  So we need to figure out a way to track what has been reviewed.  We could use pairs of tags like @rene added.  So if we review each pair in turn, and then grab more pairs once those are done?

Comment: @JasonMArcher [here is the SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266852/tags-distribution-on-the-major-legal-tags-non-legal-related) I used. Not all tag communities are open for moderation activities but we could check in each dedicated room to see of they are willing to help.

Comment: Just noticed [tag:proprietary] (and a synonym) which can probably be added to this list.

Comment: Many of the `android` ones will pertain to the Android License Verification Library, which has its own `android-lvl` tag.

Comment: @CommonsWare so you are saying that most of those 161 should be re-tagged?

Comment: @rene: Particularly if your objective is to burninate `licensing`, `android-lvl` will be a more apropos tag for many of those. Questions regarding Play Services licensing APIs and such would be relevant for SO, so downvotes would not be an appropriate measure. I have re-tagged some already and will continue working on them over time.

Comment: @CommonsWare that is true. I'm not familiar with android but if there are some easy guidelines on when to retag I'm happy to help out. I've added your retag suggestion to the to-do list

Comment: @rene: The simplest rule is "if the post mentions 'LVL' or 'License Verification Library' by name, it's an `android-lvl` question". After that, I'd leave it up to Android folk; I'll be continuing to retag throughout the day.

Comment: We aren't necessary trying to burn "licensing".  It has on-topic uses.

Comment: Please do not 'burninate' [tag:gnu]. It's used for software tools and gnu extensions for C and C++ as well.

Comment: @Deduplicator GNU make, GNU grep, etc.

Comment: @Rapptz: I thought that was under "gnu extensions"...

Comment: GNU is on this list due to the GNU public license. My [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266852/tags-distribution-on-the-major-legal-tags-non-legal-related?tag=gnu) shows a lot of those question go together with [tag:c]. I tried asking in [the Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23951783#23951783) if maybe [tag:gnu-c] would be useful. To be clear: It is not the goal to burninate the tag, the goal is to get all legal related questions closed. Those last ones are less easy because the tag is used in several contexts. @Rapptz

Comment: At what point are we going to consider [tag:licensing] "done"? I've started moving on to [tag:open-source] but I see that the tag is still listed.

Comment: @KevinBrown If we believe that the tag is clean enough to give active followers the chance to keep the tag clean without our effort and that not many cases exist that can be used as evidence that legal stuff is OK tp ask. But I'm afraid that is not a hard number. I can run my sede query again on sunday to see what is left? I'll do the same for GNU and open-source.

Comment: Proposal:  In order to finish up licensing, how about we review all the open questions that are left from 2013 thru 2015 (less than 100 questions).  Once we have closed any off-topic questions, we will know that the vast majority have been closed, including ALL in the last 2.5 years.  I'm out of votes today, but I don't think there will be more than 40 off-topics left in that range.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I can live with that...

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding any very bad questions under [gnu].  I vote we give it a clean bill of health.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I tried to find some as well and didn't succeed. I'm in favor to declare gnu healthy.

Comment: I just found the [foss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foss) tag (**F**ree and **o**pen-**s**ource **s**oftware). Should we work on it as well ? (Just a few dozen questions)

Comment: @Pang Yes, good catch.

Comment: I think we are very close to cleaning up the last tag.  I think I have read through all the currently open questions and I had 1 vote left over for this 24 hour period.

Comment: OK, there is a close vote event in 15 minutes, we will see those last ones in the queue...

Comment: We can mark this [status-complete].  Well done everyone!  Any lingering issues with [open-source] can be delt with in [Let's clean up open-source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284976/lets-clean-up-open-source).

Comment: @JasonMArcher FYI [I added more clarity about licensing questions here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298715/1768232)

Comment: "All questions are off-topic and closed or locked... [lgpl]", umm... no, there are +200 questions.

Answer (score 22):

### Progress summary

**Click [Run code snippet] on the bottom** to see it.
Data are based on [the other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal/295218#295218).

```js
"use strict";

// Get data from the post.
$.ajax({
 'url': 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/295218?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!SWJ_BpAceOT6L*G2Qa',
 'type': 'GET',
 'jsonpCallback': 'processReply',
 'dataType': 'jsonp'
});

// Process reply.
function processReply(replyData)
{
 // Write log for reply data.
 if(window && window.console && window.console.log)
 {
  window.console.log(replyData);
 }

 // Get HTML of the post.
 var htmlString = replyData['items'][0]['body'];

 // Define tag info dictionary.
 var tagInfoDict = {
  // Data comes from revision 144 of the other post.
  // https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295218/144
  'gnu': {'closedCount': 115, 'openCount': 1231},

  // Data comes from revision 140 of the other post.
  // https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295218/140
  'licensing': {'closedCount': 2426, 'openCount': 303},

  // Data comes from revision 115 of the other post.
  // https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295218/115
  'agpl': {'closedCount': 59, 'openCount': 0},
  'apache-license': {'closedCount': 141, 'openCount': 0},
  'artistic-license': {'closedCount': 3, 'openCount': 0},
  'bsd-license': {'closedCount': 88, 'openCount': 0},
  'closed-source': {'closedCount': 68, 'openCount': 0},
  'commercial': {'closedCount': 155, 'openCount': 0},
  'copyleft': {'closedCount': 18, 'openCount': 0},
  'copyright': {'closedCount': 88, 'openCount': 0},
  'cpl': {'closedCount': 5, 'openCount': 0},
  'creative-commons': {'closedCount': 58, 'openCount': 0},
  'disclaimer': {'closedCount': 14, 'openCount': 0},
  'eula': {'closedCount': 32, 'openCount': 31},
  'gpl': {'closedCount': 824, 'openCount': 0},
  'gplv3': {'closedCount': 88, 'openCount': 0},
  'intellectual-property': {'closedCount': 64, 'openCount': 0},
  'legal': {'closedCount': 429, 'openCount': 0},
  'lgpl': {'closedCount': 286, 'openCount': 0},
  'mit-license': {'closedCount': 152, 'openCount': 0},
  'mpl': {'closedCount': 21, 'openCount': 0},
  'mspl': {'closedCount': 18, 'openCount': 0},
  'non-gpl': {'closedCount': 10, 'openCount': 0},
  'patents': {'closedCount': 37, 'openCount': 0},
  'terms-of-use': {'closedCount': 91, 'openCount': 0},
  'trademark': {'closedCount': 17, 'openCount': 0},
  'truelicense': {'closedCount': 2, 'openCount': 3},

  // Data come from search results at 2015-06-17 01:27:00Z
  // http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+%5Bproprietary%5D
  // http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+%5Bproprietary%5D
  // http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+%5Bproprietary-software%5D
  // http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+%5Bproprietary-software%5D
  'proprietary': {'closedCount': 19, 'openCount': 0},
  'proprietary-software': {'closedCount': 25, 'openCount': 0},

     // Late addition [foss]
     'foss': {'closedCount': 52, 'openCount': 0},

     // Last tag done
     'open-source': {'closedCount': 3291, 'openCount': 607},
 };

 // For each list item...
 $('<div/>')
  .append(htmlString)
  .children('ul')
  .children('li')
  .each(function()
  {
   var listItem = $(this);
   var links = listItem.find('a');
   if(links.length < 3)
   {
    return;  // Should have at least 3 links.
   }

   // Get info for tag.
   var tagName = links.eq(0).text();
   var closedCount = parseInt(links.eq(1).text(), 10);
   var openCount = parseInt(links.eq(2).text(), 10);
   if(isNaN(closedCount))
   {
    return;
   }
   if(isNaN(openCount))
   {
    return;
   }

   // Update dictionary.
   var tagInfo = {
    'closedCount': closedCount,
    'openCount': openCount,
    'isInProgress': true
   };
   tagInfoDict[tagName] = tagInfo;
  })
 ;

 // Write log for tag info dictionary.
 if(window && window.console && window.console.log)
 {
  window.console.log(tagInfoDict);
 }

 // Get summary.
 var totalClosedCount = 0;
 var totalOpenInProgressCount = 0;
 var totalOpenDoneCount = 0;
 var tagCount = 0;
 for(var key in tagInfoDict)
 {
  if(!tagInfoDict.hasOwnProperty(key))
  {
   continue;
  }

  var tagInfo = tagInfoDict[key];

  totalClosedCount += tagInfo['closedCount'];
  if(tagInfo.hasOwnProperty('isInProgress'))
  {
      totalOpenInProgressCount += tagInfo['openCount'];
  }
  else
  {
   totalOpenDoneCount += tagInfo['openCount'];
  }
  tagCount++;
 }
 var totalCount = totalClosedCount + totalOpenInProgressCount + totalOpenDoneCount;

 // Calculate dates.
 var startDate = new Date('2015-05-24T01:31:03Z');
 var currentDate = new Date();
 var timeElapsed = currentDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();  // In milliseconds.
 var timeRemaining = ((totalClosedCount + totalOpenDoneCount) > 0 ? timeElapsed / (totalClosedCount + totalOpenDoneCount) * totalOpenInProgressCount : 0);  // In milliseconds.
 var endDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + timeRemaining);

 // Update UI.
 $('.total_count').text(totalCount);
 $('.closed_percent').text(formatPercent(totalClosedCount / totalCount));
 $('.closed_count').text(totalClosedCount);
 $('.open_done_percent').text(formatPercent(totalOpenDoneCount / totalCount));
 $('.open_done_count').text(totalOpenDoneCount);
 $('.open_in_progress_percent').text(formatPercent(totalOpenInProgressCount / totalCount));
 $('.open_in_progress_count').text(totalOpenInProgressCount);
 $('.start_date').text(formatDate(startDate));
 $('.current_date').text(formatDate(currentDate));
 $('.end_date').text(formatDate(endDate));
 $('.tag_count').text(tagCount);
 $('.progress_percent').text(formatPercent((totalClosedCount + totalOpenDoneCount) / totalCount));
 $('.progress_bar').css('width', formatPercent((totalClosedCount + totalOpenDoneCount) / totalCount));
}

function formatPercent(inputValue)
{
 return (inputValue * 100.0).toFixed(1) + '%';
}

function formatDate(inputDate)
{
 return inputDate.toString();
}
```

```css
.result_box
{
 font-size:150%;
}
.progress_bar_background
{
 background-color:#000;
 position:relative;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.progress_bar
{
 background-color:#0f0;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br>
<div class='result_box'>Completed: <span class='progress_percent'>Loading...</span></div>

<div class='progress_bar_background'><span class='progress_bar'></span></div>

<br>

<div>Closed: <span class='closed_count'></span> (<span class='closed_percent'></span>)</div>
<div>Open (Done): <span class='open_done_count'></span> (<span class='open_done_percent'></span>)</div>
<div>Open (In Progress): <span class='open_in_progress_count'></span> (<span class='open_in_progress_percent'></span>)</div>
<div>Total: <span class='total_count'></span></div>

<br>

<div>Started: <span class='start_date'></span></div>
<div>Current: <span class='current_date'></span></div>
<div>End: <span class='end_date'></span> <i>(estimated)</i></div>

<br>

<div>Number of tags: <span class='tag_count'></span></div>
```

Comment: 50% reached at around 2015-06-08 05:00:00Z

Comment: 100% reached around 2015-07-05.  [open-source] declared almost clean of off-topic questions and can be handled [on its own](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284976/lets-clean-up-open-source) now.

Answer (score -10):

I think that legal questions should be allowed if they are about the following topics:

```
Specific programming problems
Software algorithms
Coding techniques
Software development tools
```

The reasons are very simple. The legal factor is very important in the Software Development. Before starting to code, we need to have at least a notion of the factibility of our solution.

I already read the following post: [How do we handle ethical/legal questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280151/how-do-we-handle-ethical-legal-questions)

And I disagree with the answer. It is a waste of time to code something illegal. The legal factor has something to do with the programming. In the other hand we are not lawyers, but here in Stack Overflow there are newbie programmers(mostly students) and experienced programmers. This tab will preferably help the newbies because they usually can't afford to hire a lawyer to solve a small concern about a particular software algorithm he is considering to use for example. I think the experienced programmers can give some directions to the newbies so they don't commit stupid mistakes.

I don't think we need to be lawyers to know that kill a person is illegal in most countries. In the same way for experienced programmers some legal question could be obvious, but for a newbie not.

Comment: You are clearly not understanding the first item you quoted... a **specific programming problem** is about a specific problem with a piece of code.  If you haven't started writing anything, then you don't have a specific programming problem, you have a design problem.  As such, the question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Some design questions are on-topic for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but as always, you should consult the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first

Comment: Fair point, but what about a software algorithms for example? And I still can write a piece of code as a prototype just to ask if it is legal. I know that this rule of legal equal to offtopic is legendary, but I think we have to reconsider it.

Comment: But you still aren't asking for a problem with a specific piece of code.  You are asking about the design of that code.

Comment: If I have a problem with the design then it is a programing problem. Programming is not equal to coding(http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~penny/teaching/csc2123/phases.html). Even if you are right, Stack Overflow let me ask something about the four topics I quoted so I still should be able to ask legal questions about the other three topics.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you want to ask these questions on Stack Overflow, but the simple fact is that no matter how your try to spin it, a legal question about an API, library, software algorithm, piece of code, etc is still a conceptual question and not a practical one, and thus is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -27):

Legal stuff is part of life, and part of software development, too.

If someone is interested in this aspect of the subject, he should be allowed to use the related tags.

Thanks to tags, there can be no cluttering due to subjects that are not strictly technical.

Comment: These kinds of questions have been off-topic at Stack Overflow for years.  Having off-topic tags encourages off-topic questions (I have already had 1 person try to justify their question with that logic).

Comment: @JasonMArcher: Saying the tags are off-topic is not quite right for some of them. Admittedly, even the better tags attracte orders of magnitude more off-topic than on-topic questions, with answers at best boiling down to "that's my guess, but ask a lawyer", or even a straight "ask a lawyer".

Comment: True, I didn't mean to imply that all the tags are off-topic.