# Abuse of duplicate marking?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I came across this question here: [How can I make a for-loop pyramid more concise in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382433/how-can-i-make-a-for-loop-pyramid-more-concise-in-python)

The question was marked two days ago as a duplicate of this: [Python nested looping Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885234/python-nested-looping-idiom)

I looked at the "better" question and came to a conclusion that it should not have been marked as a duplicate. The user who marked is possessed the dupe hammer. Looking at the "better" question again, the accepted answer belongs to the user who marked the other question as a duplicate?

Is this appropriate? What should we do about this?

Comment: Yes, it is appropriate. That's what we gave the gold badge holders dupe hammers for. You can always vote to reopen if you disagree.

Comment: I have seen a specific high-rep user erroneously dupehammer (always to their answers) in the css tag on quite a few occasions as well. I'd be curious about this question in general. I'm not sure that your specific example is valid though.

Comment: Note that the *answers match*, the target post answers the question stated.

Comment: The new question is *two years* after the first, and appears to be the same. If it didn't have an answer, the duplicate closure would be correct, I don't see why it *having* an answer changes that.

Comment: I thought duplicates were now being used to determine the better of two questions. It just seemed suspicious to me that it was only two days ago, and that the user who marked it answered the other question.

Comment: @Zizouz212: Mar 24 is two months ago, not two days.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, must of thought it was may... Oh well. :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Gold badge holders have been given this power *precisely* because they know where the canonical questions are located. Often they have written those answers themselves.

The duplicate vote was entirely appropriate, the target post answers the question stated: *use `itertools.product()`*, which is what Kasra also answered with.

If you disagree, the community can always still vote to re-open the post. I do advise you to check with the (very active) Stack Overflow Python community in the [Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python); they track [canonical Python questions](http://sopython.com/canon/) for duplicate voting. They list a [different canonical](http://sopython.com/canon/46/flattening-a-nested-for-loop-dynamic-nested-loops/) (no, this doesn't mean we need to rush in and close the other post).

Under certain circumstances, a merge may be warranted; if a new *answer* adds new insights but the canonical *question* is better worded, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I never really thought about looking out to the chatroom. :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 I myself am agree that its duplicate,although i mentioned using `zip` and a bit different explain but its duplicate :).

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the questions are actually duplicates, then no it isn't abuse because marking duplicates is *exactly* what this feature is for. Yes, there's some additional motivation for dup-closing in favor of your own answers - that too is intentional, since there's already a considerable amount of motivation to be had in just *re-answering* duplicates if your only goal is to garner rep. Closing reduces duplication of answers, so a bit of extra motivation for answerers to write re-usable answers instead of dozens of bespoke replies is to everyone's benefit.

You can disagree about which question should be the *target*, but that doesn't change anything - and when in doubt, picking the older question is a quite reasonable default.

As usual, if you feel that **both** questions have useful answers then flag the duplicate and request that a moderator merge the two of them together.

Comment: Hey... I thought [you were on vacation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal#comment198052_295218) :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I know same, this is a surprise! Anyways, thanks for the insight. It looked slightly weird, especially since the marked question looked better, so I'd thought I would raise it here.

Comment: You'd believe what that guy says? Clearly he needs to check his sources...

Comment: [*cough* *cough*](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3486141#3486141)

Comment: @rene you'd believe what that guy says?

Comment: @Shog9, FYI: This answer is quoted in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338826/3773011). In my opinion, that answer is taking your statements here significantly out of context; ascribing meaning to them with which I consider it likely you don't agree. If I was the one being quoted, I would want to be specifically informed in order to have the opportunity to clarify if my statements were being misinterpreted, or not.