# Says I reached my daily vote limit for comment upvotes?

Tags: support, comments, upvotes

Getting a weird "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 23 hours" error message after I attempt to upvote a comment on SO.

The new UTC day started 14 minutes ago. I don't think I even upvoted any comments within the last 14 minutes, and already getting this error. I've tested on multiple comments by upvoting them, but they all give the same error.

I rarely even vote on comments on SO. Maybe like 2 a day? I doubt I even voted much on comments yesterday either. Not something I really have ever maxed out on before, unless I maybe tried to once a long time ago, but maybe I didn't even max out then.

So I'm almost certainly positive that I'm incorrectly receiving this error message.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Oh, I think I may know what caused this.

I have been in the close vote queue, closing many off-topic license questions lately. So I guess when I vote to close as custom off-topic reason that already is there, it upvotes that comment automatically. There is a campaign to close these off-topic legal questions, as shown [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/3041194).

Ok yea, just double checked, and it does correctly show an upvote from me on them. The reason it didn't show on some is b.c I already used my comment upvote limit.

Comment: It's not an upvote.  There isn't even an option *to* vote in that queue.

Comment: If you vote to close as a duplicate or anything like that, it does it automatically for you. `possible duplicate of blah blah blah`....

Comment: That's exactly the same situation that I'm facing. You solved my mystery, [Roombatron5000](http://web.archive.org/web/20150531133640/http://stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/roombatron5000)... no, wait, I mean, [Dronehinge](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/dronehinge).

Comment: Ouch. That's pretty painful. I guess the upvotes should be made by Community instead, then!

Comment: @NathanTuggy I wonder if [Community♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) can upvote the same comment several times (once for each user voting to close with the same custom reason).

Comment: @Pang: Seems to do just fine on spam.

Answer (score 11):

[You only get 30 comment upvotes a day.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/175248)  You may have been upvoting a ton of comments in the queues.

Comment: I flagged 15 comments in four minutes the other day (obsolete, too chatty). The link seems to say I shouldn't have been able to. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: @BillWoodger You can use as many comment flags as you have available, maxes out at 100 to use per day. The "30 comment upvotes or deletes per day" is referring to you can delete up to 30 of your own comments per day. (which those are unrelated to flagging since you can't flag your own comment)

Comment: @Dronehinge thanks, but it was this bit in the link which confused me: "5 comment flags/day", immediately before the 30 stuff.

Comment: @BillWoodger idk.. probably that is the initial amount of comment flags a user has, but with successful helpful comment flag history it rises to up to 100?

Comment: @Dronehinge No, you start with 10 flags. Perhaps only 5 can go to comments? I don't know.