# Raise upvote limit for comments (in review queue?)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, comments, comment-votes

When I'm in the **review queues**, I'm diligent about **upvoting existing comments** that provide important and relevant feedback to the author. (This also happens automatically if you [duplicate canned review comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296256/3025856).) The goal is to add weight to existing feedback in hopes that it's taken seriously.

The problem is that there's also a [**daily limit of 30 comment votes**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256384/limits-on-upvoting-comments). I suspect that's reasonable for most contributors. If you're diligently upvoting existing feedback while reviewing 20-40 posts in 2-3 queues each day, however, you'll hit this with some regularity.

Given this, I'd like to suggest either:

1. Establish a *separate limit* for comment votes in the review queues, or
2. Increase the comment vote limit for *all* contributors to e.g. 80 votes (if not more).

The former is more targeted to this problem, and would have the least spillover effects. But it also seems like a lot of extra engineering (as detailed by [@Makyen in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410631/raise-upvote-limit-for-comments-in-review-queue#comment859038_410631)) for a comparatively small set of contributors. As such, the latter would be dramatically easier, while still [safeguarding against automated abuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256403/3025856) (assuming that's the primary reason for this limit).

I acknowledge that this probably only affects a really small percentage of contributors. But I'd argue that we should *encourage* reviewers to upvote useful feedback, and this limit can restrict that effort.

> **Edit:** As highlighted by [@zcoop98 in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410631/raise-upvote-limit-for-comments-in-review-queue#comment859008_410631), raising the vote limit would *also* be really useful here on Meta Stack Overflow as well, since these questions often end up with more comments than answers.

Is this too marginal of a gain to provide much benefit to the community? Are there other opportunities for abuse I'm overlooking?

Comment: I've never really understood this limit tbh. The abuse vector is *exceedingly* limited since comment votes are really inconsequential and not liked to reputation... and I consistently run out just browsing meta, so there's that too.

Comment: @zcoop98: Agreed. I've read a handful of explanations for the limit on various threads, but a lot of them come across as motivated reasoning, or some false dichotomy between 30 votes and unlimited votes. I understand having _some_ limit, but it's not clear to me that doubling or even tripling the current limit would cause any real issues.

Comment: @zcoop98: Also, that's a really good point about Meta, specifically, since the nature of [tag:discussion] threads encourages much longer comment chains than on the main site.

Comment: I've ran out of votes a lot more on meta than on main. Would prefer seeing the limit completely removed rather than raised though, largely for the reasons already outlined in the comments. I mean, [what's the worst that could happen?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: Separate buckets for votes in the review queues have always been a good idea. Naturally they've never been implemented.

Comment: @TylerH That's probably in part because many ways of implementing such limits would be easy to circumvent (i.e use outside the review queues). There could be a difference in the request sent to the server based on being on a review page, but that would be relatively trivial for someone to get around, unless it's a single request which does "submit review and perform this other action, if the review was valid". Implementing that is substantially more complex, particularly if there are multiple possible additional actions, than just adding an extra call to the "upvote this comment" endpoint.

Comment: @Makyen What's there to circumvent? They *already* successfully track sub-context votes (you get n per day or n+5 so long as you use the extra 5 on answers before your last one in the n pile is used, or something like that) per day. It should be straightforward for them to say 'you get 40 votes of type `x` per day on stackoverflow.com, and an extra 40 per day on 'stackoverflow.com/review'.

Comment: @TylerH Tracking a difference in what you voted on is relatively easy and can't be spoofed. Tracking *what page you were viewing when you voted* can be spoofed with relative ease.

Comment: Oh...!?, so the Limit is 30, I was wondering indeed, as I hit it "today" for the first time ever, because of the "large" Thread on Meta about the annoying Change about "Last seen" & "Joined SO x time ago" with 35 Answers and [20-50] Comments per Answer. Got an Error Msg that I had hit the "Daily Limit" and had "to wait for 8h", but 5h later I can upvote Comments again (here), so even that Error Msg is "not correct"...

Comment: @Makyen Maybe you could prevent spoofing by increasing the comment limit for reviews only if a review was done (maybe even for the specific comment)

Comment: @chivracq Those daily limits are *per site* (with per-site meta sites considered as separate sites). So, you can upvote 30 comments here on MSO, 30 on MSE, 30 on SO Main, and 30 on each of the 170+ main SE sites, *and* 30 on each of the matching 170+ per-site meta sites.

Comment: @shaedrich Yes, it would be possible to not count a single comment upvote (or on multiple comments) on any post for which you've actually submited a review within X time. It's just not easy to differentiate if you upvoted those comments while viewing the review page.

Comment: I kind of agree with this request.. on the other hand I have to wonder if you are not overdoing it. You shouldn't need to add more weight to all the important comments, if a comment already has say at least 10 updoots then maybe just let that one be and save the points for comments that still really need the help to stand out. My reasoning: if it manages to get to 10, there is no reason other people are going to stop updooting it. It has already gotten the "high number" perk at that point.

Comment: @Gimby: That seems like a useful heuristic. In the review queues, though, comments rarely have more than a couple of upvotes, and many have zero, since these are new posts. And that’s especially true when reviewing answers in _First Posts_ or _Late Answers_ where they likely haven’t had much  traffic, and they’re unlikely to stick around for long enough to get much more. In that case, I want to make sure any existing feedback has the perception of community backing for the author to take it seriously. I’m not sure how effective that is, but it’s a discipline I try to maintain.

Comment: @+Mod, Thanks for the Explanation..., which should stand in the buggy Popup like: "You've reached your daily Limit (30 x 3 per 8h) on [Main/Meta.Site/Domain], you now have to wait for 8h before you can like a Comment on the same Sub-Site again."... - And "daily" = per 24h, just saying...

Comment: @JeremyCaney (whoops, I missed that reply). So essentially you already are saving your comment updoot points only for comments that really need it. Fair enough, this request already had my upvote anyway :)