# Are questions about using a licensing API off topic because of the word "license"?

Tags: discussion, scope

A [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11693100/535871) from three years ago asking for guidance on using the Google license validation API was just closed for being "not about programming". I was asking about the behavior of Google's API and about a license check algorithm I was considering implementing at the time. The question had nothing to do with legal issues or about licensing in general: it was about using the API and the behavior of Google's Android license check server. (Just to clarify: the term *licensing policy* is Google's terminology for a piece of code the developer writes as part of an app. It does not refer to "policy" in a legal sense.)

One of those voting to close left a couple of comments, to the effect that the question "pitches towards licensing." Frankly, I don't know what that means and I certainly thought I was asking about a programming problem.

I'm not put out about this particular question being closed. However, I would appreciate some guidance as to just how this question crossed the line and whether it could be salvaged.

Comment: It looks plenty programming/algorithm related to me, though I could understand how people would close the question just based on "license" and "legal" keywords.

Comment: I would vote to reopen but I don't have quite enough rep yet ...

Comment: Your post fell victim to the [legal cleanup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) that is taking place. In future cases you might also drop a message in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where we have enough regulars to cast re-open votes if needed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When I read title I thought : this will be blatantly off topic because of *Google Play* and *licensing*.

Then I read calmly the *loooong* question and realized that is was about an algorithm to control access rights on an application, and asking for possible weaknesses or other problems.

So the reason for close is definitely not correct, as the question is about *a software algorithm* which is the second line for an on-topic question in the help center.

Is your question clear would be another problem, because I had to read it many times (English is not my first language) before I could understand what the question really was, but it:

- shows research
- is about *a software algorithm* so is on topic
- is understandable even if it needs some effort

IMHO it should not have been closed and I voted for re-open.

Comment: from your analysis it looks like [tag:algorithm], [tag:access-rights] (and possibly also [tag:design]) tags are better fit for the question than [tag:licensing]

Comment: @gnat : absolutely - I often do not pay enough attention to tags, but IMHO access-right would be much better than licensing which is irrelevant here.

Comment: I cast the last reopen vote.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback (and for the reopen votes!) I see how the title is misleading; I edited it to get rid of both _Google Play_ and _licensing_. Perhaps using the LVL acronym will avoid the bad first impression. I'll try to be more sensitive to language issues like this in the future. Partly why the question is long is that I expanded it to address points raised in comments to the thread.

Answer (score 5):

I cast the first close vote on your question that day, so I owe you an explanation.

I read your question several times before casting my vote, and it sounds like you're looking for comments on the algorithm you proposed, or suggestions on alternative algorithms, or comparison to other algorithms, which, to me, is somewhat *primarily opinion-based* or *too broad*.

Some may agree with me, some may not. Since the community has now decided that your question should be kept open, I guess your question should be classified as a [Good Subjective Question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/); that is, it's subjective, yet constructive.

However, I strongly disagree with [the close votes which says that your question is about licensing or legal issues](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Da8w48UtdJIJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/11693100/would-this-google-play-licensing-policy-be-safe-to-use), since it is definitely not.

Anyway, thank you for bringing this up. I'm always learning, and I'm sure that I'm now more in line with the stance and viewpoint of the community. I will keep on contributing by posting, voting, flagging, etc., and hopefully make Stack Overflow a better place for all of us.