# Blacklist [copyright]

Tags: discussion, blocklist-request

This summer some regulars started the process of [cleaning up the legal-related tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117/359284), which is still ongoing (even though it's marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but that's a different issue). Many of the tags have been burninated (including [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal), along with many others), but there is one tag that just keeps getting new questions: [copyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyright)

It *was* empty (without tagged questions) [on December 4th](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27321206#27321206), but then on December 9th I noticed something was wrong, because the tag still existed. [So we burninated it, again.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27431278#27431278) On December 14th [it was still alive with a question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27536701#27536701), so another shot was taken at burninating the tag.

This past Friday (December 18th), I [noticed the tag was still around](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27635233#27635233) because **it just won't die**. And even after deleting the last question in the tag, [it came back from the dead today](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27664494#27664494).

So given that **the tag has come back 5 times in 16 days** because users keep asking off-topic questions with the tag, I think it deserves to sit on the blacklist. It's clear that it will not die naturally, like most of the other tags, and we're going to need some extra help.

---

I've since discovered that [there are locked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcopyright%5D+is%3Aq) in [copyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyright) that are preventing the tag from being removed, and that's why people can still make new questions with the tag. So blacklisting the tag will fix this issue, but the real problem is that these two questions (which are *locked* and thus *cannot be flagged*) have the tag on them. There is a [feature request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250840/tags-that-only-exist-on-locked-questions-should-we-treat-these-the-same-as-tags) that would also solve this issue by ignoring locked questions when removing tags.

Comment: And that new blatantly off-topic question even got upvoted...

Comment: It doesn't get removed because there are locked questions that has the tag http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[copyright]+is%3Aq btw, each question has less than 2k views per year (sql one at 12609 and pirate at 5932), check again in a week, and maybe we could get both deleted too.

Comment: @Braiam: My FR to change that on MSE: [Tags that only exist on locked questions, should we treat these the same as tags that don't exist at all?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250840/tags-that-only-exist-on-locked-questions-should-we-treat-these-the-same-as-tags)

Comment: I'm generally one who argues for preserving locked questions, but maybe 5 years is long enough :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to stop this.  Copyrights last for 70 years in the USA ;)

Comment: Just noticed that this one has no punny title... apparently hats dulled meta

Comment: @Braiam It's never too late to think of one and edit it in.

Comment: Well SOCVR is in the process [of burning it again](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33067598#33067598). This tag seems fireproof.

Comment: I just burninated it. Again...

Answer (score 4):

The obvious (at least to me) solution to this is to add `locked` status to tags. This allows for older questions with a given tag to exist while not allowing new ones to be created with it.

I cannot see any problems or negative effects of being able to lock a tag (other than the "inconvenience" that someone has to implement it). Am I missing something?

Comment: This is actually what blacklisting does. Old questions can still exist, but edits cannot be made to old questions, and new questions cannot be created, if it has the blacklisted tag.

Comment: No, this is not the same, [Blacklisting a tag removes all occurrences of it from the target site ...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist-request/info).

Comment: @hlovdal no, it doesn't, just prevents questions from being created or edited with the tag. The tag wiki/excerpt is wrong