# I have not created the tag, only using popular tag but still showing validation "Create tag only after 1500 reputation"

Tags: bug

I was posting a legal law-related question on Stack Overflow, and I was not creating any new tags (just using the popular tag "Legal-Issue"), but it is still giving me a validation message. So what should be the reason for this? Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Refer to this image:

[image]

Comment: Why are you even trying to post that question on Stack Overflow? SO is for programming questions. Are you looking for [Law Stack Exchange](http://law.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It's apparently [a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?search=legal) for the deleted legal tag. In any case, do not post that to Stack Overflow. It is not on-topic.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara good spot. I've removed that synonym now since neither tag should really exist

Comment: Mike M. as I had the question and it was showing the tag related to that so that I have posted here on stackoverflow. Some people was asking for spider-man and superman related questions so why can't I ask if I have real issue with that. :( and Thanks for answer Alexander, I will not ask next time after you have removed the tag :).

Comment: @dinesh there are a bunch of sister sites. This is probably where you saw the superhero question....

Comment: Ya I think you are correct @Patrice.On stackoverflow, I was redirected to popular tags and their I found tag related to my question so that I misunderstood. I accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You're posting a legal-centric question on Stack Overflow.  **We're not lawyers.** You should consult lawyers, specifically ones dealing with matters of estates.
- Your question doesn't relate *in any way* to programming.  It would be closed and downvoted immediately as being off-topic.

The tag creation logic seems to be correct - [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal) was [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117/1079354) (or "deleted") by the community sometime last year.  I would imagine that it has been blacklisted as well, but I can't find any proof in what I've linked to supporting that assertion.

Comment: Ctrl-F on the blacklist page returns 0 hits for legal slightly surprisingly