# Will Licensing questions become on topic once Programmers.SE changes scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

Programmers.SE is revamping its scope and will become solely concentrated on Software Engineering.  With this new format, [software licensing questions will be considered off topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8205/698).

In the comments to that answer there are some guesses as to where these software licensing questions should go, including [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) and [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Nothing against OS, but not all licenses are open, and as far as Law is concerned, who can trust a lawyer?

Should SO welcome practical software license questions that our user base has? Or does the phrase *"we've found that these categories of questions are a poor fit for the site, for various reasons"* actually mean "these questions are almost universally crap so to the devil with them!"

Comment: Aw @bluefeet, fun hater :(

Comment: always @Will always!

Comment: So, who's responsible for adding humorous comments under meta questions when Will is the OP?

Comment: Do you have some examples of what "practical" may mean in your normal use case?  I'm on the fence since I could see some benefit to it, but I see a *lot* of room for not-so-good questions, too.

Comment: @makoto Something not like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174052/concise-description-of-all-common-software-licenses-for-the-average-programmer (hangs head in shame).  I thought I asked (but cannot find now) a question about how two different licenses applied to the same software library "merged".  Would the more restrictive or more permissive library apply?  That had a definite impact on whether or not I used the library.

Comment: I'm hesitant to know what "Will Licensing" involves.

Comment: my understanding is licensing is going to leave Programmers primarily because other sites simply have proven to handle this topic _better_. Consider taking a look at licensing questions at these sites and _after_ that, ask yourself if Stack Overflow can handle this topic better than them

Comment: I feel compelled by the law of the internet [to link to a certain old Meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169210/159251) in response to this question.

Comment: Just to be complete, a lot of licensing and legal questions were handled in the legal burnination: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/578411

Comment: Perhaps there should be a Software Licensing.SE specifically for dealing with this, possibly as a counterpart to Open Source.SE?

Answer (score 30):

I don't believe that licensing question will ever become on-topic at Stack Overflow, unless we will change the main focus away from questions about *programming* (which licensing doesn't fall under).

Comment: Licenses *are* practical issues faced by programmers in their job.  It's not a perfect fit, no, but there are plenty of edge cases that still find a home here.  I hate those damned .htaccess questions, but they're barely on topic so they stick around.

Comment: @Will _"Licenses are practical issues faced by programmers in their job"_ Sure, but not a _programming problem_ actually.

Comment: I've experienced them as such.  A library I wanted to use had two different licenses applied to them, one more permissive than the other.  If I couldn't be covered by the more permissive license, I'd have to skip the library.  That was very practical, and had a very large impact on my task.  See?  Borderline.

Comment: @Will I know your pains, but these kind of problems are really _Borderline_ at best. What should such questions look like? Asking for alternative libraries? That would be off-topic as well.

Comment: Carpal tunnel issues classify as practical or even daily issues for many developers too, but we're not doctors. SO only covers the core of programming, let's not change that.

Comment: @Kyll you're stretching.  If you aren't careful, you'll hurt yourself.  Ooh!  Was that a ripping sound I just heard?

Comment: That's all I'm saying @πάνταῥεῖ, they're borderline.  We accommodate other borderline but relevant question types.  As to your "look like" question, that particular example looked like "I've got a library covered by permissive license A and restrictive license B.  If A wins, I can use the library.  If B does, I can't.  In these cases, which license applies?"

Comment: @Will, That's actually highly dependent on the type of licenses used there. Also there are lawyers specialized upon that topic. Our company has employed one for exactly that for example.

Answer (score 6):

In response to @Makoto's answer, and comments therein (reproduced below), I was drafting a reply which was probably too long for another comment.

---

If a license can "impact development decisions", then it becomes a question of "which license [to] use", which then turns into the off topic reason of "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"

--CDSpace

Yes, I describe that as one of my chief major concerns. It could work out; it could turn into another variant of a shopping question

--Makoto

---

I'm saying it shouldn't be a "major concern", it should be a reason licensing should be off-topic. I don't believe it will work out.

It will either turn into "well if I can't use this license, what other packages can I use" and we'll end up with a default list of duplicates (rather like a license FAQ, which can probably be found elsewhere) to which all future license questions can be referred, which is not in the spirit of SO.

I think this echo's what is discussed in the comments of πάντα ῥεῖ's answer as well. But I think we shouldn't stretch to try to include licensing questions as "borderline", but make them out-right off-topic, possibly including a flag reason as well.

Comment: Not all licensing questions would be recommendation questions. For example: "I'm using license X. Can I use a library with license Y with this project?" Hopefully the questions would be more interesting, but I hope that explains that there's the shopping list side (bad) and the practical side (good).

Comment: I think the practical side you're defending would simply attract "yes/no" answers, increasing the noise. If any more substantial answers come it, I think they would be more legal in nature rather than hands-on-the-keyboard solutions. And shouldn't the managers have the final say on what license to use, not the developers?

Comment: This is sort of what I alluded to as being a concern rather than an absolute prohibition.  It's possible to allow questions that talk about whether or not these licenses are compatible with each other insofar as development goes (in my mind); what's not okay is to ask us which license should be used.  As to your point about the managers:  if you're *lucky* they may be in the loop, but it's seldom anything they'd deal with; at best you'd get them to run it up the chain until it eventually makes it way into Legal's hands.

Answer (score 3):

I'm tentatively okay with the idea that license questions can become on topic for a few key reasons:

- A license can **genuinely impact development decisions**; if a license is too permissive or requires all modifications to be shared upstream, that may pose a very serious problem for developers.
- I've borne witness to a few questions here on Stack Overflow that were at least tangentially related to licensing trouble; I recall a poor user attempting to use `git rebase` to completely undo all contributions that someone had made to their project because of a bad license.

However, I'm not confident that it'll work out for a couple of reasons:

- **We lack the expertise.** Let's face it; many of us here aren't accustomed to having to deal with licenses on a daily basis, and although it would be unfortunate, the visceral reaction to a question that can't be answered is that it gets ignored, or worse, downvoted.
- **We need a much, much clearer line of what is acceptable or not.**  We may get this parade of questions to the tune of, "What license should I use," which is the masses crowdsourcing their legal license work.  Not something I'm a fan of.

Comment: "I recall a poor user attempting to use git rebase to completely undo all contributions that someone had made to their project because of a bad license." That's like saying that Home Improvement.SE should handle questions about environmental regulations because there was a contractor who had to pull up some toxic floor tile that his employee installed by mistake. The broader _reason_ the task needs to be performed isn't really relevant to the details of the execution of the task in either case.

Comment: What Josh says - personally I’d *love* to be able to ask licensing questions on SO, but it doesn’t feel right.

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  Yes, that's mostly what I'm saying.  It's only tangentially related which would mean that it'd make a really crappy licensing question (but a *very* interesting Git question).

Comment: Hm, I thought you meant that as a point in support of licensing being accepted.

Comment: @Josh I see that as as an example of a license question that, if asked up front, would have prevented the need for the rebase in the first place.

Comment: If a license can "impact development decisions", then it becomes a question of "which license [to] use", which then turns into the off topic reason of "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"

Comment: @CDspace:  Yes, I describe that as one of my chief major concerns.  It *could* work out; it *could* turn into another variant of a shopping question.

Comment: That's not a licensing question, that's a git question with a motivation that happens to be about licensing. If that question gets asked the licensing part would be removed and just left as "I want to remove all contributions from an user, how to do so?"

Comment: @Braiam my take on the example from above http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335060/will-licensing-questions-become-on-topic-once-programmers-se-changes-scope?noredirect=1#comment398204_335063

Comment: @PaulCrovella the whole discussion is about amending the scope to allow certain licensing questions, since they won't have one in a short while.