# Is a question on-topic if it's about programming but the problem that needs to be solved isn't?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, xy-problem

Are "XY"-type questions on topic if the problem the OP was trying to solve is off-topic for Stack Overflow but the question they're asking is?

Example:

Bob has a problem with his computer (on-topic for Super User) and tries to solve it with programming (on-topic here), but doesn't know how, so he asks a question on Stack Overflow.

Related: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Follow-up question : What should be done about "off-topic" answers to XY questions in these scenarios? If Y is not the correct way to do X, answers usually explain why Y is wrong and how to do X. But what if X is off-topic?

Comment: I'd love to see a real life example of this.

Comment: I'll link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73659118/larger-batch-size-cause-larger-loss?noredirect=1#comment130089354_73659118 as an example. The real question is a statistics one, not a coding one, but the OP didn't know this at the time of posting and thus asked for explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

The acceptability of the question is dependent on its subject, not its background.

A good example was mentioned [the other day by Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335063/603977):

> I recall a poor user attempting to use `git rebase` to completely undo all contributions that someone had made to their project because of a bad license.

That isn't a legal question. It's a question about doing something specific with git, so it fits on Stack Overflow.*

This is the inverse of the principle that [simply tacking "...while programming" on to the end of your otherwise off topic question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) doesn't make it on topic.

It's the specific thing that we're here to answer questions about, not the context, that's important.

---

*Contingent of course on it also being a good question.

Comment: Good to see that example having other Meta applications.

Answer (score 2):

If the asker has no idea about how to program a solution, then it's a too broad question.

If the question is about a specific issue the asker encountered when programming the solution, then it's on-topic. But explaining the full situation might be noise.