# Offer option to prioritize the close vote queue by number of close votes already cast

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Every time I go to do a review task, it always seems like the close vote queue is approximately 100x bigger than any other. So that is where I spend my review time. I've noticed that as I review questions, they seem to have a variable amount of close votes already cast, from a low of 2 up to 4.

I'm suggesting that we offer (at least as an option) the ability to prioritize or sort the queue such that any candidate questions with 4 votes already cast, are shown to the reviewer before any with 3, and those before any with 2. (I suppose it's possible that this is the case already, and the observed variability is actually just dynamic votes getting cast as I am clicking on the questions to review them, but that seems unlikely to explain what I see fully and consistently.)

The logic is simply that I think this would have the effect of knocking the queue down more quickly (at the fastest rate, on average, per vote cast in the review queue), although I don't have science/math/experience to back that up. Actually I was hoping that [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261831/what-is-the-sort-order-of-the-close-vote-queue) would inform me about what the current priority formula is, but the answer was a general one rather than a precise formula (and does not seem to suggest that number of close votes is used in calculating priority).

Comment: Hmm, I'm the author of that answer. It really should explain what the strategy is. Can you indicate what is unclear about or should be clarified because I'm happy to add that.

Comment: I honestly love this suggestion, I have been skipping some posts that have fewer close votes, to optimise the chances of my vote not aging away. And that is within the guidance of the http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers which has helped immensely.

Comment: ["The queue already works this way... Sorta: the more previous reviews a given task has had, the closer to the top of the queue it'll be..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773)

Comment: @rene I guess I was looking for a clear statement that identified queue priority.  Instead it seems there are at least 2 criteria (number of previous reviews,  queue entry time) that are combined in some not-mathematically-specified way to create a "priority".  Although it explains the general "strategy" it's not as crisp as actually giving a formula.  In any event, that statement is not the central issue in my question, which is asking for an option to prioritize by actual close votes rather than any other metric, including the the number of previous reviews.

Comment: And this feature request is pretty much a duplicate of the one @gnat linked (on MSE).  I don't know why I missed it in the comments of the question I linked.  Hmm.  I guess you can't mark an MSO question as a duplicate of an MSE question.

Comment: OK, I expanded that answer a bit also based on feedback I got in the SOCVR room

Comment: That might very well be the most important bump by community I've ever seen.

Comment: I wrote a userscript a while back that uses the API to filter by delete votes and close votes (min and max) as well as many other useful filtering options. I've developed it to the point now where I use it to also find good questions in need of answering. [Magic Tag Review 2](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/MagicTagReview2.user.js)

Answer (score 2):

That's an excellent and logical suggestion, which could help in cutting down this Sisyphean work.

Now there's a catch: I fear that people will start "roboclosing" questions with 4 close votes. And after that they'll "roboclose" questions with 3 votes, and on, and on (I'm not saying it doesn't happen now, but at least it happens on *any* question, not the ones with the highest close votes already). Even with audits, that would mean that the first 2 people voting to close influence further reviewers, impatient to get rid of all those "about to be closed" questions.

If I'm presented with Java questions, since I don't know much about that, I'm unsure to close. Seeing 4 close votes would probably influence me to "nail the coffin" (and maybe another user already voted from 3 to 4 following the others...).

That would mean that I would have to set a filter for my favourite tags to be sure of my decision.

I'd prefer the idea of granting gold tag badge users more power on other categories than "duplicate" and/or give some silver tag badges more power.

For instance, user owning the [python] gold tag badge and filtering on Python duplicates is in the best position to hammer all duplicates in 1 action.

If it was possible to cast more than 1 vote for "unclear/too broad" when questsion has the relevant tag badge (like talked about on Stack Exchange: [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders)), that would also solve it, but giving the power to the people who know better (sorry if you think I'm being elitist, I'm not).

Comment: Actually, this was done once https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251493/792066