# Review tasks with few reviewers are forgotten by the system

Tags: bug, review-queues

To validate a review, it requires multiple people to vote for the same action. We know that reviews are automatically removed after two weeks.

But I found some review I participate such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/31724853), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/31432719), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/31704686) that **has been taken by the review system, receive some votes but not enough to finish it**. It means not enough people vote to close the post (or not). These reviews were subsequently removed. This results in partial reviews that are not useful.

To ensure that this occurs, I made an SEDE query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1751020/review-not-finished-but-removed-per-month) that show the **amount of review task started but not finished** per months :

[image]

*The query search for all review task that are "aged away" and have at least one review (excluding skip).*

For me, there is an issue. Instead of focusing on some posts to finish most review, it starts multiple review then forgot them, so they finish aged away. Reviews are scattered between multiple posts.

At the end, we have enough review to conclude more reviews than now, but some are not validated. Instead of showing review that is already started, it show now one. If we shows less review but to more people, we will complete more of them.

I would like to add that no, it's not because of missing voters. If you have 2 reviews that are not fully managed, just ask those people to review the same post instead of looking for multiples.

Comment: Correct, close votes age away if they don't accumulat fast enough. What's your question here?

Comment: Close *reviews* age away faster than votes if no action is taken as well.  Otherwise the Close Vote review queue would be even larger than it already is.

Comment: To vote to close a question, one does not need to go in review - on the question you linked, the review had 2 close votes, and then a third user VTC'd the post on April, 3rd (note [the lack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1) of CV reviews on that day for the 3rd closing user).

Comment: I just added question. And yes, I know @RyanM but here it's review with some vote at begin, not like 2h before outdated review cleaning

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. As you've been told already, [close-votes age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223). I didn't like that feature when it was introduced, but it's been 7 years now and it's still here, so I don't expect it will change any time soon. That's what happened with your first three linked examples. For your fourth example, [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71711182/revisions) was closed by votes from 3 users, and then it was later re-opened. The rules of how many votes are required to close is the same: 3.

Comment: @CodyGray I know about aged away, and I think it's necessary, but why review that already have some votes are not more showed to reviewers to prevent the aged away. Because at the limit, if all review received 2 votes, no one will be done, even with lot of votes

Comment: So, this is a [[meta-tag:feature-request]] proposal to increase the "weight" of close-vote reviews where there are already 2 votes to close? See, e.g., [Offer option to prioritize the close vote queue by number of close votes already cast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312680) and [another one on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222201).

Comment: No it's a bug request because of review item are not well taken

Comment: The system does prioritise questions with more close votes in the review queues if it can. I still don't understand what you're asking here and why you think it's a bug.

Comment: The system is working as designed (i.e., this is not a bug), unless you consider "not enough close vote reviewers" a bug.  If you want to change the design, that's a feature request.

Comment: the basic problem, is that people who spend a lot of time here, are more than unhappy of the review system and so the queues are full. the best solution is too enhance the bit that it  closes more questions automatically

Comment: What's not clear in my post??

Comment: If the 'bug' is that the system shows new posts instead of posts that have already gotten some review votes, and you want to show the already reviewed posts instead, then that would be a feature request (and not a bug) and it would not be needed because the system already works like that, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue/199912#199912. Or maybe you want to make a feature request to make this mechanism more strict, for example _never_ show new reviews if there are posts with existing review posts available, or always use a [...]

Comment: [...] first-in-first-out order on the queue? If so then you should specify that in the post (and change it to feature-request because it is not a bug).

Comment: Well, mini-feedback about "*What's not clear in my post??*", your Post is a bit difficult to read, the wording is a bit "obscure", nearly all sentences are a (grammatical) mix of Singular + Plural or even present + past tenses, "*it appends*"(!?) = you probably mean "it happens"... // You generically mention "*Review(s)*" in the whole Post, "*vote to close*" only comes once halfway, clearly mention that you are talking about the "Close Votes". // Then clearly mention your "Proposition" / *Feature-Request* and what you would want to change to the System, instead of insisting on a *Bug*...

Comment: Hum, "funny" Side-Note: "*Asked 10 months ago*" + "*Closed 11 months ago.*" ...!?!?

Comment: @chivracq https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347355

Comment: @cigien, oh...!?, yep indeed, that's the same "*very-minor-pedantic-bug*", ah-ah...!

Comment: @chivracq The "Close vote" mention were before editing. The problem is on all queue, that's why I removed tag, but all comment are talking about it. For the Grammar, sorry for this. I'll try to edit to fix, thanks ! Finally, no it's not a feature request as it's not working as designed : review are forgotten and not finished instead of beeing done

Comment: Well "*on all queue[s]*" still sounds a bit vague to me, I think you should still clearly mention explicitly which Queues you mean, your 3 Examples are all related to the 'Close Votes' Queue. // I only have access to a few Review Queues for [>0.5k <-> <2k] Users, and I've never seen Posts age away in 'Suggested Edits' / 'First Qt's' / 'Late Answers', only in 'Flagged (by myself) as Duplicate', but I answer a very small Tag with no Users with >2k-Rep, so my Flags always age away... // Well for grammar/syntax/etc, hopefully some User with some "proper" command of English will edit your Post...

Comment: @chivracq I made some changes for grammar. Hope it's better now. I show only close reviews because it's only the one I checked. For Suggested edit it's different as it's limited. For First Q/A, I know there is age away too, I could add example if you really want