# What influences what order you'll see questions in in the review queues?

Tags: support, review-queues

How are things sorted in the review queues? What determines what order you'll see the posts in? Will everyone see all posts in the same order (assuming that they have the same filters)?

Do things like current number of close/delete votes and post score influence the sort at all?

I do realize that the sorting of the close vote queue was addressed here: [What is the sort order of the Close Vote queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261831/what-is-the-sort-order-of-the-close-vote-queue)

However, do other queues (VLQ, Triage, etc.) work similarly?

Comment: It follows a ["garbage-first"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html) collection strategy.

Comment: @rene Do other queues work like that, too (e.g. the VLQ and Triage queues)? I was asking about them, too.

Comment: I dunno, anyway: this is how the CVQ works: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311384/578411

Comment: @rene Good to know, that helps... I'd assume that the other ones work kind of like that, but I'm not sure.